# Python - MySQL - Unknown columns 'http://www.......................' in 'field list'

Tags: python, mysql, sql, mysql-python, mysql-error-1054

I'm trying to select a record from my MySQL db, the problem is that it returns with this error which i don't understand, i searched on the web for a solution, and there are many similar cases, but none apply to this specific one.

The expression i'm trying to execute is the following:

```
result = cursor.execute("""select * from urls where domain = '%s';"""%(found_url,))
```

it is in a try clause and it always goes right to the except giving me this error:

```
OperationalError(1054, "Unknown column 'http://..................' in 'field list'")
```

(i omitted the url, the dots act as placeholders)

after some cycles, being in a loop, it stops giving me that error and changes it to this:

```
ProgrammingError(2014, "Commands out of sync; you can't run this command now")
```

any idea? i'm going crazy on this one.

Comment: `import MySQLdb`
>>> `db = MySQLdb.connect(host="localhost", user="root", passwd="pass", db="name")`
>>> `cursor = db.cursor()`
>>> `cursor.execute("""select * from table_name where some_column = '%s';""" % ('kfkfk',))`
`0L`

Comment: weird, I've tested this on my env and have no errors

Comment: You should **not** be using string interpolation. Use parameters: `cursor.execute("""select * from urls where domain = %s""", (found_url,))`

Answer (score 0):

Use query [parameters](http://mmxgroup.net/2011/07/14/pythons-mysqldb-parameter-placeholders/) instead of how you are doing it with string interpolation. The protects you against [SQL Injection](http://xkcd.com/327/) [attacks](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SQL_injection).

```
cursor.execute("""select * from urls where domain = %s""", (found_url,))
```

Notice the differences here:

- The `%s` is NOT quoted, as the MySQLdb library will handle this automatically
- You are not using string interpolation (no `%` after the string to replace your placeholders). Instead, you are passing a tuple as the second argument to the `execute` function.
- Since you are only using one place holder and you still need to pass a tuple, there is a comma to indicate it is a tuple `(found_url,)`